# Android attrs.xml null issue

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, attr

I am trying to set the name of the drawable in my `mainActivity.cs` file through `attrs.xml`.

attrs.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
<attr name="logo_name" format="string" />
</resources>
```

Style.xml

```
 <item name="logo_name">"@drawable/icon_volvo"</item>
```

In MainActivity.cs

```
namespace Decisiv.Droid
{
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", Icon = "?logo_name", MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, NoHistory = true)]

public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
```

When I use a hard coded string, it works but not this way. Any Help?

Comment: Try this with this change 
`<attr name="logo_name" format="reference"/>`
`<item name="logo_name">"@drawable/icon_volvo"</item>`
to

    `<item name="logo_name">@drawable/icon_volvo</item>`

Comment: still gives the null value. the logo is not set

Comment: `mainActivity.java`? Java or Xamarin/C# as you have it tagged as `Xamarin`...